# Moving Div Box using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a 300px by 300 px div box that moves a few pixels when the user has their mouse on the box. The only thing is when the div hits the end of the browser size I want it to to start moving the other way and not make the window scroll. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<div style="left:300px; top:300px; width:300px; height:300px; background:blue;>
</div>
```

This is oleg's code that I am having trouble running in firefox, am i doing something wrong?

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
window.onload = function () {
var speed = 10, // the box will move by 10 pixels on every step
direction = 1, // 1 = move right; -1 = move left
boxElement = document.getElementById('theIdOfTheBox');

if (boxElement) {
    boxElement.addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
        // Calculate and store some of the box coordinates:
        var boxLeftPos = boxElement.offsetLeft,
            boxRightPos = boxLeftPos + boxElement.offsetWidth;
        // When right side of the box goes too far - change direction:
        if (boxRightPos > document.body.offsetWidth) {
            direction = -1;
        }
        // When left side of the box goes too far - change direction:
        if (boxLeftPos < 0) {
            direction = 1;
        }
        // Recalculate position:
        boxElement.style.left = (boxLeftPos + speed * direction) + 'px';
    });
 }
};
</script>

<style>
#theIdOfTheBox {
position: absolute;
left:100px;
top:100px;
width:300px;
height:300px;
background:blue;
}
</style>


</head>

<body>
<div id="theIdOfTheBox">box</div>
</body>



</html>
```

Comment: Can you post your current JavaScript or do you yet even have any?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Start by creating a couple of variable that keep track of speed and direction:

```
var speed = 10, // the box will move by 10 pixels on every step
    direction = 1; // 1 moves in the positive direction; -1 vice versa
```

Then grab a reference to your box and attach an event handler to its "mouseover" event:

```
var boxElement = document.getElementById('theIdOfTheBox');

if (boxElement) {
    boxElement.addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
        // Calculate and store some of the box coordinates:
        var boxLeftPos = boxElement.offsetLeft,
            boxRightPos = boxLeftPos + boxElement.offsetWidth;
        // When right side of the box goes too far - change direction:
        if (boxRightPos > document.body.offsetWidth) {
            direction = -1;
        }
        // When left side of the box goes too far - change direction:
        if (boxLeftPos < 0) {
            direction = 1;
        }
        // Recalculate position:
        boxElement.style.left = (boxLeftPos + speed * direction) + 'px';
    });
}
```

All done, here's a **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dZ7dX/)** for you to play around with.

Mind, however, the `position: absolute;` in the CSS and the fact that you need to wait for the DOM to load to be able to safely perform the `getElementById` operation.

If you want to avoid usage of offsets, you may want to parse and manipulate margins or padding of the box instead.

**Animation**

If you want to animate the movement of your box, you can try CSS animations. Just add the following to the style declaration of your box in the CSS:

```
-webkit-transition: left 0.3s 0.1s ease-out;
```

The above code will animate any changes in `left` property in webkit browsers. You can add other vendor prefixes (and none for compatibility with future releases) to enable animation in other browsers that support it.

## EDIT

Regarding your comment with running the script on browser launch:

First of all make sure to wrap the JavaScript code in `<script></script>` tags if you are embedding it in an HTML page. You can run a validator (e.g. [validator.w3.org](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input)) to ensure you have a correct document structure.

Secondly, place the code inside those tags as close as possible to the end of the body of your document, i.e. `</body>`.

You can also wrap the entire JavaScript code in a function that will be executed once the document is fully loaded. This way the code can be placed (or remotely required) from the document head (but why would you want that?). Here's how it's done:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    // ... the code goes here
});
```

A (non-recommended) alternative is:

```
window.onload = function () {
    // ... the code goes here
};
```

Or (please avoid this, it's just an example) in HTML:

```
<body onload="someFunction();">
```

So, the resulting code *might* look like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        /* ... the CSS goes here */
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="box">I'm a box.</div>
    <script>
        // ... the JavaScript code goes here
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Special note regarding Internet Explorer**

There's no support for `addEventListener` in Internet Explorer below version 9. You should use `attachEvent` instead.

Comment: Hey, how do I get this script to load when the browser launches I tried pasting in the script but nothing moves

Comment: @Gregwest85 Which browser are you using?

Comment: firefox, I posted it where I posted my question, did I input it wrong?

Comment: @Gregwest85 In the code you just posted the JavaScript is executed before the `<div>` is created by the browser. See my update on various techniques on how to circumvent that.

Comment: i tried it using the window.onload and added it in my main post but it's still doing nothing. I know it works in the jsfiddle, so im not sure why I can't get it working

Comment: @Gregwest85 I copied and pasted your edited code exactly and it works fine in Firefox 19 and Google Chrome 26. Something else is interfering perhaps? Are you running it on a server? Maybe an old version is stuck in cache? Maybe you forgot to save changes...

Comment: im gonna try updating firefox. Thanks for all your help I really appreciate it. I just have one more quick question right now the the box goes from left to right. If i want it to go up and down as well, how could I implement that?

Comment: @Gregwest85 To move the box vertically you can manipulate `boxElement.style.top` property and compute the position of the box with `offsetTop` and `offsetHeight`. You might also consider taking a look at `window.scrollTop` property if the page is intended to be scrollable.

Comment: I only want it to stay in the confines of the browser and not scroll, so for example if it goes all the way to the left could i just put boxElement.style.top = a few px inside of this  if (boxLeftPos < 0) {
            direction = 1;
        }
to make it move to the top of the browser and then when it hits the top make it do the same thing but go right.

Comment: @Gregwest85 You can. Or you can pre-calculate the position of the box before actually moving it. This way you won't end up out of bounds.

Comment: @Oleg why is window.onload a non-recommended solution? Just wondering, seems to me .onload is cross-browser even more than .addEventListener which is more IE IMO, and does not work in IE 8-

Comment: @HanletEscaño Because you cannot assign multiple event handlers with `foo.onload`, `bar.onclick` etc. Also, there's no control over the activation phase (capture/bubble). Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/EventTarget.addEventListener for more information.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
 var topPos = 0;
 var leftPos = 0;
 var leftAdder = 1;
 var topAdder = 1;
 var id;

    function move() {  
        clearInterval(id);
        id = setInterval(frame, 3);

        function frame() {

        leftPos = leftPos + leftAdder;
        topPos = topPos + topAdder; 
        document.getElementById("box").style.left = leftPos + 'px'; 
        document.getElementById("box").style.top = topPos + 'px'; 

        if (leftPos == 500) {
            leftAdder = -1;  
        }
        if (topPos == 350) {
            topAdder = -1;  
        }
        if (leftPos == 0) {
            leftAdder = 1;  
        }
        if (topPos == 0) {
            topAdder = 1;  
        }  
        }
    }

    function stop(){
        clearInterval(id);
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the description I think you want to animate the height of your div, If you are able to use Jquery you can try something like this:

```
$('.div').hover(function() {
    $(this).animate({
        height: $(document).height() - 50
    }, 300);
},function() {
    $(this).animate({
        height: '30px'
    }, 300);
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/CvhkM/4469/

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

**Javascript**:

```
var over = false;
var dir = 0;
var speed = 10;

window.onload = function () {
    var div = document.getElementById("myDiv");
    var top = 10;
    div.onmouseover = function () {
        over = true;
        timer;
    }
    div.onmouseout = function () {
        over = false;
        setTimeout(timer, 1);
    }

    var timer = setInterval(function () {
        //direction
        if (div.offsetTop >= document.body.offsetHeight)
            dir = 1;
        else if (div.offsetTop <= 0)
            dir = 0;


        if (over && div.offsetTop < document.body.offsetHeight && dir == 0) {
            top += speed;
        }
        else if (over && top > 0 && dir == 1)
            top -= speed;

        div.style.top = top + "px";
    }, 100);
};
```

**Markup**:

```
<div style="width: 800px; height: 400px">
    <div id="myDiv" style="width: 300px; height: 300px; background: blue; position: absolute">
    </div>
</div>
```

Your div has to be positioned *absolute*, the first div would represent your browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to input arrows to dictate the movement of the box, we can use this code. Try and see;

```
        <script>
            var topPos = 0;
            var leftPos = 0;
            var id;

            function moveRight() {  
              clearInterval(id);
              id = setInterval(frame, 10);
              function frame() {
                if (leftPos == 350) {
                  clearInterval(id);
                  gameOver();
                } else {
                  leftPos++; 
                  document.getElementById("box").style.left = leftPos + 'px'; 
                }
              }
            }

            function moveLeft() {  
              clearInterval(id);
              id = setInterval(frame, 10);
              function frame() {
                if (leftPos == 0) {
                  clearInterval(id);
                  gameOver();
                } else {
                  leftPos--; 
                  document.getElementById("box").style.left = leftPos + 'px'; 
                }
              }
            }

            function moveDown() {  
              clearInterval(id);
              id = setInterval(frame, 10);
              function frame() {
                if (topPos == 350) {
                  clearInterval(id);
                  gameOver();
                } else {
                  topPos++; 
                  document.getElementById("box").style.top = topPos + 'px'; 
                }
              }
            }

            function moveUp() {  
              clearInterval(id);
              id = setInterval(frame, 10);
              function frame() {
                if (topPos == 0) {
                  clearInterval(id);
                  gameOver();
                } else {
                  topPos--; 
                  document.getElementById("box").style.top = topPos + 'px'; 
                }
              }
            }

            function gameOver(){
                leftPos = 0;
                topPos = 0;
                alert("Game Over...");
                document.getElementById("box").style.top = '0px'; 
                document.getElementById("box").style.left = '0px'; 
            }
        </script>
```